# DDD execution line jumps to subroutine top @ continuation line Fortran 77

Tags: debugging, coredump, fortran77

I work with some very old Fortran code in my research lab, and have relied heavily on DDD to test new code and subroutines. Until 6 months ago I was able to generate core dumps and step through code without any fuss. Now, whenever DDD encounters a continuation line, or "&", the green arrow pointing to the execution line jumps back to where the line where the subroutine I'm currently in is started. This is annoying because I have to work back to see where the code falls down, although I use the "undo" function in DDD to see where I was. I cannot tell if it's my code or the debugger that has changed

I was wondering if anyone else has encountered this behaviour and if there is a way to stop the execution line from jumping between "&" and the SUBROUTINE lines? This also disrupts my core files, which just point me to the SUBROUTINE line as well.

I've added a code snippet of the subroutine declaration and portions of the code where the debugger green arrow jumps between the continuation lines and the subroutine declaration.

```
      SUBROUTINE SOFC_A42_coeffgen(IPCOMP,COUT,ISTATS)
      IMPLICIT NONE
```

~~~~~~~~DECLARATIONS AND A BUNCH OF CODE~~~~~~~~

```
          IF( P_battery > P_fully_discharge )
     &                                     P_battery = P_fully_discharge
C---------Determine SOC at end of time-step.
          battery_SOC_f = ( battery_SOC_p*battery_capacity
     &                      - P_battery*TIMSEC/battery_discharge_eff
     &                    ) / battery_capacity
C---------Determine heat generated due to discharging losses.
          q_battery_loss = P_battery * (1. - battery_discharge_eff)
```

Comment: Does DDD refer to GNU's graphical [Data Display Debugger](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Display_Debugger)?

Comment: Are your line terminations the same within the whole file?

Comment: Yes, it's the Data Display Debugger. Although what I'm experiencing seems to be related to the underlying GNU Project Debugger. All lines are terminated before the column 72 limit and continued with a "&" in column 6

Comment: @user3171038 While this question is almost 9 years old, I have some hopes that you were able to fix the issue? I am encountering the same, but not only with continuation lines but with almost every statement...